# Why is it important to remove whitespace from the end of a line in C?

Tags: c, whitespace

Most of the pre-commit check tools I have used with different organizations do not allow whitespace at the end of lines. What is the motivation for this? Can it cause different behaviour, increase flash memory usage, or is it just a stylistic thing?

Comment: See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/121555/281325

Comment: There is no programming reason.

Comment: It is done in order to minimize noise in commits. Allowing "freedom" in spacing it is possible that two identical contributions in terms of code are different because of just a space at the end of the line, and that would be noise (in terms of false-positive conflicting sources) from the integrator's perspective.

Comment: It also causes mild symptoms when you add a backslash *near* EOL, which will then not continue a line but cause a syntax error.